# OpenMP loop gives different result every time

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define KE 10
#define NSTEPS 100
main()
{
    float ex[KE],hy[KE];
    float bn[NSTEPS];
    int n,k,kc,ke;
    float ddx,dt,T;
    float t0,spread,pulse;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    kc = KE/2;
    t0 = 40.0;
    spread = 12;
    T = 0;
    FILE * temp = fopen("Exserial.txt", "w");
    /* Initialize */
    for ( k=0; k <= KE; k++ )
    {
        ex[k] = 0.0;
        hy[k] = 0.0;
    }
    double strt=omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel shared(ex,hy,bn) private(n,k,T,pulse,t0,spread)
    {
        for ( n=1; n<=NSTEPS ; n++) {
            T = T + 1;
            pulse = exp(-.5*(pow( (t0-T)/spread,2.0) ));
            ex[kc] = pulse;
    /* Main FDTD Loop */
    /* Calculate the Ex field */
#pragma omp critical
            {
#pragma omp for 
                for ( k=1; k < KE; k++ )
                { 
#pragma omp atomic update
                    ex[k] = ex[k] + .5*( hy[k-1] - hy[k] ) ;
                    bn[n]=ex[100];
                }
    /* Calculate the Hy field */
#pragma omp for
                for ( k=0; k < KE-1; k++ )
                {
#pragma omp atomic update
                    hy[k] = hy[k] + .5*( ex[k] - ex[k+1] ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double end=omp_get_wtime();
    printf( "------------------%f\n",end-strt);
    /* End of the Main FDTD Loop */
    /* At the end of the calculation, print out the Ex and Hy fields */
    for ( k=1; k <=KE; k++ )
    { 
        fprintf(temp, "%f\n",ex[k]);
        printf( "%f\n",ex[k]);
    }
}
```

parallel output (number of thread is used =4)

```
 ------------------0.013850
    0.030408
    -0.130364
    0.107690
    0.061082
    0.023526
    0.066983
    -0.030821
    -0.024117
    0.037548
    0.000000
```

serial output

```
-0.013813
-0.028405
-0.044722
-0.064258
-0.087550
-0.072226
-0.062273
-0.055638
-0.052620
0.000000
```

I don't know where I make mistake but I am getting different results in parallel program. It gives different output every time.
one more problem is there i.e when I remove `#pragma omp parallel` from top I got correct value but no time advantages. I have to add  `#pragma omp parallel` 
so need some solution.

Comment: Different results when run in parallel is a big indicator that you have data races. You also access arrays out of bounds (since `ex[KE]` is one past the end, your for loops should run until `<` not `<=`).  Also, `bn` is written to but never read, so can be completely removed.

Comment: first of all i thank you very much for your help. but still i'm getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

As @1201ProgramAlarm suggested, you have a data race.  It involves this statement inside the parallel region and outside the critical section:

```
            ex[kc] = pulse;
```

Every thread executes that on every iteration, and every thread also reads that value back.  That the reads are inside the critical section does not save this from being a data race -- the write would need to be in a critical section too (not necessarily the same one), or otherwise protected by some kind of synchronization, to avoid a data race.

But the problems here are so much larger that the data race is pretty much inconsequential.  The *main* problem is that the computation has strong data dependencies between loop iterations.  That is, when run serially, each iteration of the outer loop updates all the elements of `ex` and `hy` based on the values computed in the previous iteration.  No matter how you much you synchronize or how broad you make the critical reason, you cannot then expect the same results (or even consistent results) if you allow the outer-loop iterations to be performed in a different order, as parallelization does.

The silver lining here is that the parallelization wasn't gaining you much anyway, because almost all the work performed by the outer loop is in a critical section.  Just removing the `omp parallel` and `omp critical` directives would go a long way toward improving this code.  For such small `KE` and such simple computations, it probably doesn't make much sense to leave the inner `omp for`s, either, but if `KE` were *much* larger then you could consider leaving the parallelization of the inner loops.

Comment: I'm getting error that's why I take KE 10 but actually I have to take KE 10000 and nsteps 1000000. if take KE that much. And one more thing that you told here outer loop interation to be performed in different order, How can I do that. ###  if remove #pragma omp parallel then I'm getting correct output but parallelization is not so effective no time advantage will there.

Comment: @AKHILAKUMARGOUDA, thread management imposes non-trivial overhead, and the computations in your inner loops are very simple. `KE` of 10000 might be enough to make the parallelization of the inner loops worthwhile, but then again, maybe not.  Do test that.

Comment: The magnitude of `NSTEPS` is irrelevant, because the data dependencies involved in the calculation make parallelization of the outer loop unfeasible, as this answer already discusses.

Comment: If remove all parallelism syntax then it's my serial code. My last request to you that is there any other way to parallelism this code.

Comment: @AKHILAKUMARGOUDA, yes, it may be that the serial version is the best you can do.  The code looks like some kind of dynamics calculation, with each state computed from the previous one, so it should not be surprising that you have to compute each state before you compute the next one -- that is, serially.  As I already said, for a `KE` of 10000, you might see some improvement from parallelizing the inner loops. Perhaps that will be enough to be worthwhile, so it's worth trying, at least.

Comment: @AKHILAKUMARGOUDA, if you happen to have multiple computations of that kind to perform then perhaps it would be more effective to run several of those at a time instead of trying to parallelize the computation itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. And again thanx a lot for your valuable time.